# Reactjs doesnot allow dir="rtl" to show text RTL

Tags: reactjs, direction

```css
.rtl{
      direction: rtl;
     }
```

```js
 <Col lg="9" md="8" sm="7">
                                    <div className="blog-details-box">
                                        <div className="blog-details-banner">
                                            <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + `/assets/images/${Datas[blogId].postImg}`} alt="" className="img-fluid" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="heading" dir="rtl">
                                            <h4 className="rtl">{Datas[blogId].postTitle}</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="blog-auth_date d-flex">
                                           
                                        <div className="author-img d-flex">   
                                            <p><Link to={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/"}>{Datas[blogId].authorName}</Link></p>
                                      </div>
                                            <div className="post-date">
                                                <p><i className="las la-calendar"></i> {Datas[blogId].postDate}</p>
                                            </div>
                                           
                                        </div>


                                        <div className="blog-details-desc">
                                            <p> {Datas[blogId].postContent}</p>
                                           
                                        </div>
                                      
                                        

                                     
                                    </div>
                                </Col>
```

I am trying to show some urdu text on one of my page only. I have tried applying dir="rtl" on my

tags but it doesnot work. I have tried using react-with-direction but it only change the position of all the items on my component and doesnot change anything about the text itself. Right now it look like it does in the picture below, in this code the  tag should show the text in rtl

Comment: What is `dir="rtl"` and what are you applying it to? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Are you trying to apply `direction: rtl;` CSS rule?

Comment: yes, i also tried adding a custom css class with direction: rtl; but it doesnot work, i think maybe its cuz of react am not sure, also dir="rtl" is html tag attribute to set the direction, same thing as direction in css

Comment: Can you provide us a code example for what you are trying?

Comment: in this code the <h4> tag should show the text in rtl

Comment: Can you also include the CSS for `className="rtl"` and the value of `Datas[blogId].postTitle`? Try to provide us enough to be able to reproduce your issue ourselves.

Comment: Added the css and i also tired applying it on a div on top of <h4>, still doesnot work

Comment: I grabbed your div with h4 and CSS rule and copy/pasted into a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-doesnot-allow-dir-rtl-to-show-text-rtl-pt8fq?file=/src/App.js) and though the font is English (left-to-right) I see the justification and sentence punctuation reversed. I suspect there may be some other layout issues at play here. Can you edit back in the screencaps and provide a bit more detail about the expected behavior. (*apologies, it is a language I can't read and thus I know nothing of the grammar*)

Comment: I tried doing it as you suggested in the sandbox, it still didnt work. Instead i just used text-align: right; and it works and look alright. I am just wondering would there be an issue if i do it this way?

Comment: Correct. I was thinking you may also need to use some additional text alignment and/or justification rules, and watch for what is inherited from parent components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used text alignment right to make it work but not sure if thats a good practice or not.